# Trouble with magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: php, linux, magento, magento-1.9, move

First of all sorry for my poor English.

I'm new in magento, but I decided to use it and bought the template.
I try it intalled on my local server and all was good (openserver, windows), after that i try it installed in local server on Mac OS X. All was OK.

Problems started when I uploaded magento with template on hosting (first of all I tried intall magento on VPS hosting (linux) and after I tried install it to default hosting on linux). All steps I did with this [tutorial](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/quick-start-guide/magento-themes/v1-0/index_en.html#introduction).

Some blocks of pages are disapeared and some css  and js paths were wrong (default paths on default theme), but mostly theme is worked.
Magento's admin panel didn't change the language.

[wrong design of search and wrong css and js paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1030.jpg)

I modify the base URL database table. (table is core_config_data, I change 2 values - web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url).

I try delete /cache and /sessions in folder var/ and 
I try reindex all data.

And I change permission to all folders 755 And files to 644.

I did all tips which I found in the net.

Can somebody give me advice with these problems?